# Azure Function Cronn Expression not working in Azure Timer Trigger

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have set the cronn expression to `0 0 23 * *  2,5` so that it may run every Tuesday, Friday at 11 pm.
However when deployed to Azure, the azure function doesnt trigger. Not sure why that is happening. No error is being thrown.. If I switch the cronn expression to `0 */1 * * * *` to run every minute, it starts working as intended. But switching back to the first expression causes it not to be fired. What is it that I may be doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

I have also tried`0 0 23 * * Tue,Fri`

Answer (score 0):

The cron expression is correct. I test it in my side and reproduce your problem. It may be caused by timezone. Please check the timezone of your function, your can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-time-zones) about the timezone. If you still not sure the timezone of your function app, you can also test 24 hours one by one. For example test with `0 {nextMin} 0 * * *` and then test with `0 {nextMin} 1 * * *`, then `0 {nextMin} 2 * * *`....

Comment: Currently, there is no timezone specified in configuration so it should be defaulted to UTC. what can I do to make sure, it runs at the specified day and time without changing configuration?

Comment: @NAKDeveloper Just test with a cron in UTC timezone to check if next minute can trigger the function.

Comment: @NAKDeveloper There is also no timezone specified in configuration of my function app, but when I test with cron expression in UTC timezone just now, it can't trigger the function. So then I test with every hour(every timezone) to check if the function can be triggered at next minute.

Comment: Hi @NAKDeveloper May I know if you solve the problem ? If the problem was solved, could you please accept my answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: That did not work. If I specify a particular time, it does not fire. However if I set it to run every minute for instance from 9 am, it was firing. but not if a particular minute was specified.

Comment: @NAKDeveloper Could you please share the cron expression for run every minute(for instance from 9am) and also share the cron expression which specify a particular time doesn't work ?